# Why is IIS not serving aspx pages?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I'm deploying an ASP.NET application to Windows Server 2003 under IIS

IIS is serving html pages fine but I get a page not found when I try and serve IIS pages

Comment: Did you setup the Virtual Directory for the asp.net page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may need to "register" IIS for ASP.NET applications.  As an administrator, run the command "%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -i".  In addition, you may need to convert your web site to an application through the IIS management console.

Answer (score 10):

By default, IIS has ASP support disabled in IIS6.

> A server running a member of the Microsoft® Windows® Server 2003 family supports application server functionality, with Microsoft ASP.NET as an option that you can enable when configuring the application server role. To deploy ASP.NET Web applications to a production server, you must be sure to enable the ASP.NET and Internet Information Services (IIS) roles on the production server before you distribute the application.

See here for instructions to enable it:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9fc367dd-5830-4ba3-a3c9-f84aa08edffa.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

Other possible reason could be Web Service Extensions, where ASP.NET version could have been disabled. My other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552409/newly-installed-iis-aspx-page-not-getting-displayed) explains steps to solve this.

Comment: This was my problem.  ASP pages would work but ASPX pages were 404 not found.  Looked at web service extensions and low and behold ASP.NET v4.0xxx was disabled.  Enabled it and it fired right up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the right .NET framework is installed properly
2. Make sure the ASP.NET extension is enabled
3. Under website properties, ASP.NET tab, make sure the right version is set.

Answer (score 1):

After having this same issue and trying all of the above without any luck.  We reinstalled SP2 for Windows 2003 and this resolved our issue.  I too have seen this problem resolved a few times with the other answers.  Most of the time just reinstalling .Net 2.0 resolves the issue but not this time.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this could also be the issue:

IIS on a Windows Server 64-bit can only to run in either 32 or 64 bit mode.

In short you need to:

1) run adsutil.vbs to enable 32 bit asp.net apps on win 64

2) re-register IIS calling aspnet_regiis.exe

3) re-open IIS Manager, go into Web service extension list and ensure ASP.Net version {2/4.xxx} (32-bit) is set to Allowed

(You might need to do Steps 2 and 3 for both Framework 2.0 and 4.0 if you want to run asp.net apps on both versions)

Full details are in the following link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894435

Answer (score 0):

Another future reference in case this is helpful to anyone who used a similar path to mine.

My back end for the ASP.NET app was MySql not Sql Server, which for me meant having a mysql connector, the reason my IIS was not serving the .aspx file is because on my development environment I was using a different version of the MySql connector than the one installed on my production environment, I updated the MySql connector on the production server to match the version Im using on the development environment and it worked great.