# Newly installed IIS. Aspx page not getting displayed

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have just installed a IIS on a win 2003 server and trying to setup an asp.net website.

I have run the "aspnet_regiis" tool as well as made sure asp.net role is enabled.

When i browse a plain from withing my asp.net virtual directory, i am able to view it. but, the server won't serve an aspx page.

What should i be checking next?

Appreciate your suggestions.

UPDATE:

Found the fix. The "ASP.NET v2.0." was prohibited in web service extensions.
Steps to fix(in my case):
- Open IIS manager
- Click on "Web Service Extensions" in the nav pane
- On the right you will view "ASP.NET v2.0.*" and status is shown next to it.
- Status was "Prohibited" in my case. I changed it to "Allowed". Boom. it worked!

Hope this helps someone. Also, you look at this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008151/why-is-iis-not-serving-aspx-pages) giving other possible reasons for the issue.

Answer (score 8):

*(Copied from answer body)*

Found the fix. The "ASP.NET v2.0." was prohibited in web service extensions.
Steps to fix(in my case):

- Open IIS manager
- Click on "`Web Service Extensions`" in the nav pane
- On the right you will view "`ASP.NET v2.0.*`" and status is shown next to it.
- Status was "Prohibited" in my case. I changed it to "`Allowed`".
- Boom. it worked!

Hope this helps someone. Also, you look at this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008151/why-is-iis-not-serving-aspx-pages) giving other possible reasons for the issue.

Comment: I can not locate this "Web Service Extension" in IIS . Where to look for?

Answer (score 0):

In Server Manager, adding Roles and Features, there's the Web Server (IIS) role section, you can find the Application Development option there where you can enable the ASP.NET and .NET extensibility options.